# Contrasting solutions for visibility when inheriting from base class templates

Tags: c++, inheritance, using-directives

In the following code will fail to compile because, despite the chain of public inheritance, HasFlag is not visible in DerivedFoo.

```cpp
class BasicFoo {
    public:  bool HasFlag() const { return m_flag; }
    private: bool m_flag = false;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo : public BasicFoo {
    public:  bool Test() const { return HasFlag(); }
};

template <typename T>
class DerivedFoo : public Foo<T> {
    public:
        // HasFlag is not visible here.
        bool Test2() const { return HasFlag(); }
};
```

The *why* of this is covered in other questions.  My question is whether there is any difference between these two solutions:

```cpp
        // Option 1:  Explicitly pull it into scope from immediate base.
        using Foo<T>::HasFlag;
        bool Test2() const { return HasFlag(); }
```

```cpp
        // Option 2:  Explicitly pull it from the root class.
        using BasicFoo::HasFlag;
        bool Test2() const { return HasFlag(); }
```

Is pulling the method from the root class, which is not a class template, somehow more efficient?  There is only ever one BasicFoo::HasFlag.  If DerivedFoo<T> is instantiated for many Ts, there are, in effect, many identical Foo<T>::HasFlags.  Does that matter?

Comment: **If `DerivedFoo<T>` is instantiated for many Ts, there are, in effect, many identical `Foo<T>::HasFlags`.** This is wrong. `HasFlags` is not defined by `Foo<T>`, hence instantiating `Foo<T>` doesn't not instantiate many `HasFlags`.

Comment: In `DerviedFoo`, make it `return this->HasFlags();`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/66qszc8Y1). It's not that `HasFlags` is not visible - it's that at the time `DerviedFoo::Test2` implementation is seen, the compiler can't be sure that `Foo<T>` actually contains a member `HasFlags`. For all it knows, there's a specialization of `Foo` that is not derived from `BasicFoo`. So the trick is to make `HasFlags` a dependent name, to postpone its lookup to the point of instantiation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik:  Thanks.  I'm aware that using the this pointer solves the problem within the method implementations, but it does not introduce the names into the public interface, leaving external users of the class without access to methods that were intended for public consumption.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The external client [can very well](https://godbolt.org/z/nP77Mqjrs) do things like `DerivedFoo<int> d; d.HasFlag();`. In what sense is `HasFlag` not part of the public interface? What do you want to do, and what prevents you from doing it? Could you show the code that fails to compile when using `this->HasFlags()` rather than `using` declaration?

Comment: @237K:  I didn't word that well.  I know there is only one instance of the HasFlag method.  I could imagine, though, that as the code is being compiled, the compiler probably has to add an entry to a table for each Foo&lt;T&gt; the refers back to the one instance of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically the two solutions are equivalent. They are both using-declarations which make the `HasFlag` member available in the derived class.

> ```cpp
> using BasicFoo::HasFlag;
> ```

This might be better though, because it is not dependent on `T`, and the compiler can diagnose whether the `HasFlag` member exists in `BasicFoo` before instantiating the  `DerivedFoo` class template. Intuitively, this should compile slightly faster, although it's unlikely to make any noticeable difference. When in doubt, benchmark your compilation (e.g. with LLVM's `-ftime-trace`).

> If `DerivedFoo<T>` is instantiated for many `T`s, there are, in effect, many identical `Foo<T>::HasFlags`.

This isn't true; there is only one `HasFlag` member in `BasicFoo`. The difference between the two solutions is only the name lookup, not the amount of members which is created.

#### Alternative Solutions

```cpp
bool Test2() const {
    // access to this makes HasFlag() dependent on T, so this won't fail to compile
    return this->HasFlag();
}

bool Test2() const {
    // qualified lookup also forces a delayed check, making this compile
    return BasicFoo::HasFlag();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the bit about possibly enabling the compiler to postpone instantiation of DerivedFoo get to the heart of what I was after.  I am aware of the alternative solutions you included, but I'm also trying to expose HasFlag to users of DerivedFoos.